# Place https://wordpress instead of https://localhost/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

Instead of writing https://localhost/wordpress is it possible to go to wordpress dashboard by https://wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You should create a virtual host. The easiest way to do that is to use software such as MAMP Pro (this is for Mac but there are also Windows alternatives). It has a GUI for creating virtual hosts, should be much easier if you don't want to mess up with hosts file, etc.